# sample database for mysql fulltext

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sample-data

I need a sample database dump for testing the performance of mysql fulltext search feature. I need around 1-10 million rows.

Would this be available anywhere? If not, what is the simplest way of generating this database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tested various full text solutions. See [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

I used the StackOverflow data dump to test.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/

It's in XML format, but it wasn't too difficult to write a script to turn the XML into SQL to load it into a database for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can download some `StackOverflow` [real data](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Check the following [link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) for more details.

You can check the following [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26557) for more details about how to restore it.